# Why does my horse break the lead I tied him to the rail with?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I always tie my horse up to a rail outside my house, but whenever I come back to him he's wandering around the yard. If I'm lucky the lead broke and I can pick it back up, but often the lead has despawned.

I don't understand why on flat ground the horse wont stay tied to the rail or fence with the lead.

Can someone tell me why this horse always breaks the lead?[image: Horse broke the lead]

Comment: I think this has to do with chunk loading, but I'm not 100% sure. I've seen it too, for sure.

Comment: This is a known and reported bug, that is present up to the current pre-release (1.8.2-pre4) at this moment. I'll link the bug report here for future reference: https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-14826

Comment: Arrggg - this is still a problem in 1.9!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a common problem sadly i dont think there is a fix for it
you just need to wait for the next patch.

here is a forum post about it
http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/1884637-163-one-major-thing-they-need-to-fix/

Comment: your question asks why if you are really interested they mention some possible reasons in the forum but i dont think its a fixable problem

Comment: Of course it's fixable, one need only change the fence block's data to ensure it spawns when the chunk loads, and if all else fails guess which animal it should belong to. It's better to fix temporarily than to allow horses to wander off into oblivion.

Comment: If you could post a link to a solution so i could improve my answer it would be much help. If you want you can also provide your own answer.

Comment: Ohh, you mean a fix that doesn't require changing minecraft's code? No, one would have to make a mod to fix this. i.e. rather than mojang working on it, someone in the community makes a temporary fix until they get around to it. I don't know if they've fixed it in 1.8, but if not it might be worth sending out a request to the community.

Answer (score 1):

Theres really no way to stop it at the moment (its a glitch and it just happens randomly) so I don't take chances and I just put my horses in a small room or even in the house. Monsters have also accidentally killed some of my horses so I just completely avoid leaving them outside unless in a fenced in pasture.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I've determined that in leu of the lead working, just building a fence box with the corners missing does a good enough job of keeping a horse alive and near me :)

Answer (score 0):

Take an Anvil and put a name tag in there. Name it put it on your horse. Give your horse it's saddle and armor or whatever your putting on it. Then rope it. IT should stay now.